# How to select struct column in spark dataframe dynamically?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to infer the schema for struct and constructing a list which contain struct fields (enclosed with col , replaced : with _ as alias name) in the select column list of dataframe.The struct fields(properties) are optional so I want to construct the select statement based on input data.

Schema Inferred with :

```
  val listOfProperties = explodeFeatures.schema
     .filter(c => c.name == "listOfFeatures")
     .flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields).filter(y => y.name == "properties").flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields)
     .map(_.name).map(x => "col(\"listOfFeatures.properties."+x+"\").as(\"properties_"+x.replace(":","_")+"\")")
```

Outcome of above statement : (val listOfProperties )

```
col("type").as("type")
col("listOfFeatures.properties.a").as("properties_A"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.b:P1").as("properties_b_P1"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.C:ID").as("properties_C_ID"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.D:l").as("properties_D_1")
```

Select Statement:

```
explodeFeatures.select(listOfProperties .head , listOfProperties .tail : _*)
```

But the above statement failed to parse at runtime. Instead if I use the below hardcoded it succeeded.

```
explodeFeatures.select(
col("type").as("type"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.a").as("properties_A"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.b:P1").as("properties_b_P1"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.C:ID").as("properties_C_ID"),
col("listOfFeatures.properties.D:l").as("properties_D_1"))
```

Constructed a List due to the below reason ,

Need to access the struct variable ,
Need to rename the struct variable because it contain : in column name.

Could anyone help me why hardcoded statement works but not the listOfProperties .head , listOfProperties .tail ?

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve '`col("type")`' given input columns: [type,
>   listOfFeatures];;

Comment: Is `listOfProperties` a `List[String]`? If yes, it should be `List[Column]` looking at the expressions in it.

Comment: yes due to concat of col values its Seq[String]. How can I cast to Seq[column] it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, your variable is a `Seq[String]` which when passed to `select` looks like `df.select("col(name)")` which makes it look for a column with the name `col(name)` instead of `name`. You need to change your last `map` as follows:

```scala
val listOfProperties = explodeFeatures.schema
     .filter(c => c.name == "listOfFeatures")
     .flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields)
     .filter(y => y.name == "properties")
     .flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields)
     .map(_.name)
      .map(x => col(s"listOfFeatures.properties.${x}").as(s"""properties_${x.replace(":","_")}""" ))
```

<sub>Side note: Use String Interpolation. It's cleaner!</sub>

Comment: Thanks, replace was not working I can do some workaround, But explodeFeatures.select(listOfProperties .head , listOfProperties .tail : _*) was showing error. How can I select all column ??

Comment: Use `select(listOfProperties : _*)`

Comment: Great its expected result.